# Checkbox menu error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with my Jquery Checkbox menu and none checkbox menu.

1. When I check example the windows top checkbox and then check the php checkbox and uncheck the windows checkbox and check it again the php checkbox is not checked.
2. I want to add the same functionality to the support label it should also counts its children checked checkboxes.

Here is my code live: http://jsfiddle.net/H2z9G/4/

The HTML should stay **intact**.

Jquery:

```
$('.payload').hide();



$('.checkGroup > input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
    $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload').toggle( $t.is(':checked'));
    if( !$t.is(':checked') ){
       $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload input[type="checkbox"]')
           .attr('checked',false);
    }
}).trigger('change');


$('.checkGroup input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   $c = $(this);
   $c.closest('.checkGroup').find('label > span b').text( $c.closest('.checkGroup').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length );
}).trigger('change');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkGroup">
<label for="search_windows_is_true"><span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px;">WINDOWS<b>0</b></span></label>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true">
    <div class="payload" style="display: none;">
        <label style="background: none repeat scroll 0pt 0pt rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); height: 20px; margin: 0pt;">
              <span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px; font-weight: bold;">PHP</span>
              <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[php_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" style="top: 4px;" name="search[php_is_true]" id="search_php_is_true">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="checkGroup">
<label for="search_windows_is_true"><span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px;">WINDOWS<b>0</b></span></label>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[windows_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[windows_is_true]" id="search_windows_is_true">
    <div class="payload" style="display: none;">
        <label style="background: none repeat scroll 0pt 0pt rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); height: 20px; margin: 0pt;">
              <span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px; font-weight: bold;">PHP</span>
              <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[php_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" style="top: 4px;" name="search[php_is_true]" id="search_php_is_true">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nonecheckGroup">
<label for="search_windows_is_true"><span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px;">Support<b>0</b></span></label>
    <div class="payload" style="display: none;">
        <label style="background: none repeat scroll 0pt 0pt rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); height: 20px; margin: 0pt;">
              <span style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 6px; font-weight: bold;">PHP</span>
              <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[php_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" style="top: 4px;" name="search[php_is_true]" id="search_php_is_true">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```